# Linking to more than one Page via User Input

Tags: javascript, html, input

So, with my code, Im trying to make this bar go to multiple urls based on what I put in. Like, "Take me to cats" will send me to "cats.com". Im trying to go to multiple html pages based on various words from the user. How do I do this? If you could do this it would help alot.

Here is the code:

```js
/**
 * Step 2: In your JavaScript, attach an event listener to the input element.
 */
document.getElementById('url-bar')
  .addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    // The keyCode for the "Enter" key is 13.
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
       let urlValue = event.target.value
      window.location ='Store.html';
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* The browser window */

.container {
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

/* Container for columns and the top "toolbar" */

.row {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

/* Create three unequal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
}

.left {
  width: 15%;
}

.right {
  width: 10%;
}

.middle {
  width: 75%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Three dots */

.dot {
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Style the input field */

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: -8px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #666;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Three bars (hamburger menu) */

.bar {
  width: 17px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  margin: 3px 0;
  display: block;
}

/* Page content */

.content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column left">
          <span class="dot" style="background:#ED594A;"></span>
          <span class="dot" style="background:#FDD800;"></span>
          <span class="dot" style="background:#5AC05A;"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="column middle">

          <input id="url-bar" type="text" value="/Home">
        </div>

        <div class="column right">
          <div style="float:right">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <h3>The Poke Browser</h3>
        <p>Surf for Things in the Poke World</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Thats the code. I was able to only get it to take me to 1 page based on ANY input instead of a specific input.

Answer (score 0):

youhave to seperate the search value which is entered by user using some kind of seperator such as space or , in your search text field. Then you can make use of split function of javascript to create a array of search url and iterate through it to open it seperately using forEach loop. Sharing with you the codepen link -

https://codepen.io/hims89/pen/WPVjLX

you can make use of IFFY for registering events

```
            (function(){
            var seperator=" ";
            var searchref=document.getElementById("search");
            searchref.addEventListener("keypress",function(ev){
                if(ev.keyCode===13)
                {
                    var urlarr=searchref.value.split(seperator);

                    urlarr.forEach(function(rec){
                        window.open(rec,"_blank");
                    });
                } 

            });


            })();
```

Comment: I tried that. But Im confused how to set the keyword to go to a specific page. Like typing "Cats" goes to "cats.com"

Comment: you can maintain a mapper object for mapping the search keyword with the url  and use the
 mapping object for redirection to a particular site. 
 codepen link -https://codepen.io/hims89/pen/WPVjLX           
                 var mapper={
                    "cats":"cats.com",
                    "dogs":"dogs.com"
                }

However such a mapper may become very lengthy if you start to add features for many keyword.
 You could make use of regular expression for mapping the keys.